# Line 2 of code is the only one that works

Tags: acrobat, calculated-field

Line 4 of this code won't work but there is no error code. It's a building permit application form. If the applicant chooses any category but New Residential from ConstructionType dropdown the minimum fee is 60 for a deck under 401 sq. ft. & .15 x value of Deck text field for a deck >=401. These work. If New Residential is chosen the fee is strictly .15 x value of Deck field. This is the part that doesn't work. Here is the code.

```
var nDeck = this.getField("Deck").value;
if( (nDeck >0 ) && ( nDeck <= 400) ) event.value = 60 ;
else if(nDeck >= 401 ) event.value = nDeck *0.15 ;
else if ( ConstructionType = "New Residential" ) event.value = nDeck *0.15;
else event.value = 0 ;
```

Comment: try using proper syntax (curly braces etc.); this might help find you logical errors. Or even write down a simple flow diagram. You might actually see that the "Construction Type" test will never be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmh, at least
ConstructionType = "New Residential"
must be
ConstructionType == "New Residential"

HTH, Reinhard

Comment: I got it worked out. I was not taking into consideration that the one "Deck" category would only be used in conjunction with a new residence and therefore not subject to minimum fee.